# insert substring into new column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a db where one column contains 2 pieces of data, e.g. first and last name.

The format is roughly `ABC-1D23-4F34`

I want to copy and insert the first 3 letters, the ABC, into a new column. Lets call these columns `[full_id]` and `[ref_id]`

From reading it looks like substring is able to do this but I am doing something wrong here.

`INSERT INTO [ref_id]`

`SUBSTRING([full_id], 1, 3)`

`FROM db.Name`

Thank you for the help.

---

EDIT:

The update string worked. But I found that there are issues with my data and it is not all in proper formatting.

Is there a way to write a case where if the substring is not 3 letters it writes a null value?

Thanks again, and sorry for having bad data.

Comment: What do you mean if the substring is less than 3 letters?  If value in FULL_ID is less than 4 characters, substring(1,3) will return the entire value.  So, are you saying if the length of FULL_ID has a length of less than 3, put NULL in the ref_id column?

Comment: ok, so the format is intended to be `ABC-12D3-34EF` BUT some of the values for the `FULL_ID` are `1234567` or `ab-12345` and so if the string at the beginning is not ABC I want a null value in the `REF_ID` column. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE Name
SET ref_id = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',full_id) = 4 THEN SUBSTRING(full_id,1,3) ELSE NULL END
```

That will set the ref_id column for all rows using the first 3 characters of the full_id column.

Comment: Awesome. Seems a lot simpler now than how I was trying to do it.

Comment: See my edit, that should solve your problem.  It says "set the ref_id equal to the first three chars of full_id only if the 4th character is a "-".  If it is not a dash, set ref_id = null

Comment: Overall I am more pleased with this result than the original I asked for. Not to say I am not jumping in my seat with excitement, I am. Unfortunately, my data has more problems but I am going to try and solve these issues by studying the code you gave to me. So thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If it is a column in the same table you need to switch to an update statement.

```
UPDATE db.Name SET [ref_id] = SUBSTRING([full_id], 1, 3)
```

Comment: I would like to complicate this a little more. Look back at my edit please. =D

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want something like:

```
Update db.Name set ref_id = substring([full_id], 1,3)
```