# SQL I need multiple cases for one column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My previous question was - [insert substring into new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746573/insert-substring-into-new-column)

I have two cases I want to run on the same column.

The first -

```
SET [ref_id] = CASE 
WHEN CHARINDEX('-', [full_id]) = 4 
THEN SUBSTRING([full_id], 1, 3) ELSE NULL
```

The second -

```
SET [ref_id] = CASE 
WHEN CHARINDEX('ZZZ-', [full_id]) = 1 
THEN SUBSTRING([full_id], 5, 3) ELSE NULL
```

My `[full_id]` column data format is mainly `ABC-123D2-45FG67` BUT some of it is all numbers or is prefixed with `ZZZ-`

If the data is only numbers I want the `[ref_id]` column to be NULL.

If the data is prefixed with `ZZZ-` I want that part to be skipped.

If the data is not `ZZZ-` and starts with `ABC-` I want to copy the `ABC` (in some cases there is `AB-1234` and that should be NULL).

My code works fine except that the two strings do not function together and when I run them separately they cancel out the work of the previous query.

How can I run both and end up with NULLS only for the data in formats like `123456` and `AB-1234`

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this just a case (hah!) of nesting your case statements?

```
SET [ref_id] = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('ZZZ-', [full_id]) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING([full_id], 5, 3) ELSE 
  (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', [full_id]) = 4 THEN SUBSTRING([full_id], 1, 3) ELSE NULL end ) end
```

Edit: Removed "else null" towards end. Think that's better. I don't have a server available to me to test.

Comment: I was trying to nest it but it would give me errors after the first case. Gonna try yours now. =D

Comment: It gives me an error at the end of this saying `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'` I think its reffering to the last `ELSE`

Comment: wow, tried deleting the else null from inside the () but not the outside. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a single case statement for this:

```
SET [ref_id] = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('ZZZ-', [full_id]) = 1 
                    THEN SUBSTRING([full_id], 5, 3)
                    WHEN CHARINDEX('-', [full_id]) = 4 
                    THEN SUBSTRING([full_id], 1, 3)
                    ELSE NULL
               END
```